# Wordpress: move site online 500 Internal error

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

Hi Hi have a working website on localhost that I want to move online.
I'm using WP 3.2.1 and I exported the DB from my localhost.
After that I just opened the .sql file with a text editor and replaced all of the 'http://localhost/mysite' with 'http://mynewdomain.com'.
After that I edited the wp-config.php file for the new destination DB online,and so I uploaded everything online.
I can see the index.php page correctly (apart from espanol,chinese etc characters broken) and few other secitons but if I try to reach the wp-admin section ..and whenever i try to browse to any another site's section I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /web/htdocs/www.***.it/home/wp-content/themes/ottaviano/shortcodes.php:55) in /web/htdocs/www.***.it/home/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
```

My htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**SOLVED:** I had to enable the output buffering and everything is fine again!

Comment: It could be a problem with htaccess

Comment: I changed the htaccess but still having issues

Comment: Is your RewriteBase correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to temporary remove your `.htaccess` file and see if you can access your admin again.

Restore you `.htaccess` and try adding:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

into the top of your `wp-config.php` if this doesn't work you also try adding the code below to the bottom of the `wp-config.php`

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and hopefully you get some error messages telling you what is going on.

Comment: I removed the htaccess and I could only display the index page

Comment: Please test yourself http://bbromaottaviano.it  I get strange errors that I don't get when I test the same site both on localhost and another server http://www.ejoin.it/ottaviano ..so weird!!!

Comment: It seems like I can access all pages but if i go to wp-admin I get the following error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /web/htdocs/www.bbromaottaviano.it/home/wp-content/themes/ottaviano/shortcodes.php:55) in /web/htdocs/www.bbromaottaviano.it/home/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934`

Comment: Actually you can access only three sections (our reputaion,rooms&rates,location) all of the other sections output the same error

Comment: Try disabling your current theme and/or your plugins, you can read here http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble on how to do that

Comment: finally caught the beast the output_buffering was killing me =).
I had to enable it.. now The also the font is displaying correct..thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem when moving a Wordpress site from one domain to the other (Error 500 - page not found).

Apparently a whitespace character found its way before the beginning `<?php` declaration in a template file.
You can trace the error by inserting a `exit("wtf")?` in `index.php` and "WTF-ing" your way to the affected file.

In my case, the reason was a move from Apple-based OS to Windows with differences in CR/LF handling.